# Modify theme's resource without copy the Control Template?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, themes, upgrade

The problem is about we are using a 3rd party control and its has a theme file provided by them.
They used to be using a centain color (unfocus selected) in one of the control (GridView) and is defined in their them file.
But not they changed the color in the theme file, so all our color changed as well.

So we want to revert back the color, there is two solution I think think of:

1. Edit their theme file, recompile and put into our project.
2. Abstract out the theme xaml and apply to all our control.

But both solution might have problem or requires redo as we upgrade our 3rd party control library.

**Because all I want to change is two SolidColorBrush resource in the theme file, is there any good way doing it on runtime or anyway to override the color?**

Note: The SolidColorBrush being used in a VisualState of a ControlTemplate.

In theme file:

```
    <ResourceDictionary
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
                    ......              
                >
        <telerik:Windows7Theme x:Key="Theme" />

.....
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ItemBackground_SelectedUnfocused" Color="White" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ItemInnerBorder_SelectedUnfocused" Color="White" />
....
```

Control Template:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="GridViewRowTemplate" TargetType="grid:GridViewRow">
.......
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
    .....
         <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="Background_Over" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Background_Over"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0"
                                                    Value="{StaticResource ItemOuterBorder_SelectedUnfocused}" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundInner_Over"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0"
                                                    Value="{StaticResource ItemBackground_SelectedUnfocused}" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundInner_Over"
                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0"
                                                    Value="{StaticResource ItemInnerBorder_SelectedUnfocused}" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
```

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing more specifics -- have you tried, for example, applying a new style to the control in question, and overriding the `ControlTemplate`?

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain in my question really well, applying a new style and overriding the ControlTemplate is what I don't want to do. Because if their Control release a new version, which will modifies the Control Template, then I will also need to redo all my work in their new Control Template.